# What is the expectation of the fourth and fifth die?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a fair die and I am allowed to roll it up to 6 times. What is the expectation for the fourth and fifth die?
So I know that the expectation of the first roll is 3.5, second is 4.25, third is 14/3.
Now do I get this right, the fourth is 1/6*6+1/6*5+2/3*(14/3)? which is 89/18?
and the fifth die is 1/6*6+1/6*5+2/3*(89/18)? which is 277/54?

and how many rolls do I need to roll before I will only accept 6?

Comment: Do you mean the expectation of the maximum roll?

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  Do you mean "you are searching for a 6.  if you get it on the first roll, you stop.  If you don't get it on the first roll, you may throw again.  And so on.  What is the expectation if you must stop at four tosses?  Five tosses?  Six tosses?"

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but can someone explain where these numbers are coming from?

Comment: @pMarkov.  I'm trying to sort that out too.  My current theory is that  the OP is trying to maximize the result of the toss.  If you have at most two tosses, say, then you take the first if it is 4, 5, or 6.  If you get  1, 2, 3, you roll again (with an expectation of 3.5).  This rule at least gives 4.25 as the total expectation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the OP is asking this question:

"Consider the following game, played with a single fair die.  A positive integer n is fixed, this is the largest number of tosses you are allowed.  Your goal is to get the highest value on a single toss. After any toss you may keep the value you just got, or you may discard your current value and toss again (subject to the n toss cap). Find $E_n$, the expected value of this game."

$E_1$ = 3.5, clearly.

To get $E_2$ note that, should you discard your first toss you will be back in the one toss game, hence your expectation will be 3.5 .  Accordingly, your optimal strategy is to keep the first toss if you get 4, 5, 6 and discard it otherwise.  Thus $$E_2 = \frac{1}{2} 5 + \frac{1}{2}3.5 = 4.25$$

Similarly, we proceed recursively.  The recursion is a little ugly as your strategy changes with n (as long as the expectation is below 5, you'll keep that first 5, and so on).
$$E_3 = \frac{1}{3} 5.5 + \frac{2}{3}4.25 = \frac{14}{3}$$

This is still less than 5 so 
$$E_4 = \frac{1}{3} 5.5 + \frac{2}{3}\frac{14}{3} = \frac{89}{18}$$

Still less than 5 so:
$$E_5 = \frac{1}{3} 5.5 + \frac{2}{3}\frac{89}{18} = \frac{277}{54}$$

(note this confirms the OP's calculation!)

Finally this is over 5!  Thus we need n=6 before we demand a 6 on the first throw.  Now the recursion becomes stable!  We get, for n ≥ 6

$$E_n = \frac{1}{6}6 + \frac{5}{6} E_{n-1}$$

So, in particular, 
$$E_6 = \frac{1}{6}6 + \frac{5}{6}\frac{277}{54} = \frac{1709}{324}$$

Assuming no arithmetic error was made (always a risky assumption).